# CycleErrors in graphlib

Tags: python-3.x, exception, error-handling, topological-sort

I'm currently learning the [graphlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/graphlib.html) of python 3.9.
And I want to generate a CycleError but when I run the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from graphlib import TopologicalSorter
ts = TopologicalSorter()
ts.add(2, 1)
ts.add(3, 2)
ts.add(4, 3)
ts.add(1, 4)

ts.static_order()
```

I don't get a CycleError.
But if I change the code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from graphlib import TopologicalSorter
ts = TopologicalSorter()
ts.add(2, 1)
ts.add(3, 2)
ts.add(4, 3)
ts.add(1, 4)

tuple(ts.static_order()) # why does this work with tuple or list ?
```

It works but why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TopologicalSorter.static_order()` is generator; function body contains `yield` statement, then the return value of function call is iterator.

Function body won't executed at all before very first attempt of extracting element from the iterator.